# Change Text Color on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, css

I have a fixed header and I want to change the color of the hyperlinks when I reach a certain position in the window.

How do i go about it in Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

listen to the scroll event and keep a check on the scrollTop...if the scrollTop param reaches your desired position, change the color of your links.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $(window.parent.document).scroll(function() {
       if( $(this).offset().top >= xxx ){
           ....change text colour...
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
$(window).scroll(function() {
var currpos = $(window).scrollTop();
if(currpos < 199)
{
if(currpos > 100)
{
$(".header").attr("color","red");
//$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.8,function(){});
}
}
else if(currpos < 299)
{
if(currpos > 200)
{
$(".header").attr("color","red");
//$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.6,function(){});
}
}
else if(currpos < 399)
{
if(currpos > 300)
{
$(".header").attr("color","red");
//$('#header').fadeTo(1,0.4,function(){});
}
}
else
{
$(".header").attr("color","red");
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body style="height:2000px;">
</body>
</html>
```

you can use various color on different window position as above

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Example html:

```html
<div id='header'>
    <a data-880='color: red'>Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using $(window).scroll() event you can check the location of window.

and base on that you can set the hyperlink color accordingly.

like this

```
 $('#links a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

try this  http://jsfiddle.net/TL9rh/